# Как соединить инпут и ид

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать табы, но не понимаю как сделать так чтобы input в положении "checked" показывал блок(display:block)
Вот как я пытался соединить:

```
#tab-btn-1:checked  #content-1,
#tab-btn-2:checked  #content-2,
#tab-btn-3:checked  #content-3,
#tab-btn-4:checked  #content-4,
#tab-btn-5:checked  #content-5 {
    display: block;
}
```

Весь код:

```
 <div class="client__blocks tabs">
                    <aside class="client__info">
                        <div class="client__info_block">
                            <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-1" value="" checked>
                            <label for="tab-btn-1" class="client__info-text">Personal details</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__info_block">
                             <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-2" value="">
                            <label for="tab-btn-2" class="client__info-text">Preferences</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__info_block">
                            <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-3" value="">
                            <label for="tab-btn-3" class="client__info-text">Payment Details</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__info_block">
                            <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-4" value="">
                            <label for="tab-btn-4" class="client__info-text">My Bookings</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__info_block">
                            <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-5" value="">
                            <label for="tab-btn-5" class="client__info-text">My documents</label>
                        </div>
                       
                    </aside>
                       <div class="client__block"  id="content-1">
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Name</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text">Igor Vensko</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Email address</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text">igor@vensko.net</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Phone number</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text">+01 123 456 789</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Date of birth</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text">Enter your date of birth</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Nationality</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text">Polska</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Gender</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text">I'm a man</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Address</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text">Poland, Bialsytok</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="client__block" id="content-2">
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Currency</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text">PLN Polish Zlotyo</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Language</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text client_icon-usa">American English</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="client__block"  id="content-3">
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Payment cards</p>
                            <p class="client__block-text">Pay with new card</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Add card</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="client__block" id="content-4">
                        <div class="client__blocks-pic">
                            <div class="client__block_pic">
                                <img src="img/Winter park.jpg" alt="Winter park" class="slider__bar-image"> 
                                <div class="client__block-signature">
                                    <p class="client__signature-text">Winter Park Ski Holiday</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="client__signature-link">Downoload pdf</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client__block_pic">
                                <img src="img/Machu Picchu.jpg" alt="Winter park" class="slider__bar-image"> 
                                <div class="client__block-signature">
                                    <p class="client__signature-text">Winter Park Ski Holiday</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="client__signature-link">Downoload pdf</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client__block_pic">
                                <img src="img/Hivar.jpg" alt="Winter park" class="slider__bar-image"> 
                                <div class="client__block-signature">
                                    <p class="client__signature-text">Winter Park Ski Holiday</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="client__signature-link">Downoload pdf</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client__block_pic">
                                <img src="img/Wadi Musa.jpg" alt="Winter park" class="slider__bar-image"> 
                                <div class="client__block-signature">
                                    <p class="client__signature-text">Winter Park Ski Holiday</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="client__signature-link">Downoload pdf</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="client__block" id="content-5">
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">ID scan.pdf</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit client__block-remove">Remove</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__block-info">
                            <p class="client__block-intro">Trip plan.doc</p>
                            <a href="#" class="client__block-edit client__block-remove">Remove</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client__block-link">
                            <a href="#" class="client__link">Upload documents</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

---

```
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.client__block {
    display: none;
}

#tab-btn-1:checked  #content-1,
#tab-btn-2:checked  #content-2,
#tab-btn-3:checked  #content-3,
#tab-btn-4:checked  #content-4,
#tab-btn-5:checked  #content-5 {
    display: block;
}
```

Извиняюсь если не понятно объяснил, если есть какой либо вопрос по коду - спрашивайте. Так же загрузил код на CodePen - https://codepen.io/hodor72/pen/wvpvxqp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну а почему это должно работать по вашему? `#tab-btn-1:checked  #content-1` означает, что блок с `id="content-1` вложен в блок с `id="tab-btn-1"`, но такого не может быть, поскольку у вас `tab-btn-1` - это `input`. Для того, что все это заработало, вам нужно чтобы `content-1` шел сразу за `tab-btn-1`, на одном уровне вложенности. Тогда вы сможете использовать селекторы типа `#tab-btn-1:checked  + #content-1`  или `#tab-btn-1:checked  ~ #content-1` и все заработает.

Однако, вы совершенно зря вешаете интерактив на html+css. Это засоряет код. Попробуйте сделать тоже самое на js. Тут он самый базовый, как раз чтобы начать.

```css
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.client__block {
  display: none;
}

#tab-btn-1:checked+#content-1,
#tab-btn-2:checked+#content-2,
#tab-btn-3:checked+#content-3,
#tab-btn-4:checked+#content-4,
#tab-btn-5:checked+#content-5 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="client__blocks tabs">
  <aside class="client__info">
    <div class="client__info_block">
      <label for="tab-btn-1" class="client__info-text">Personal details</label>
    </div>
    <div class="client__info_block">
      <label for="tab-btn-2" class="client__info-text">Preferences</label>
    </div>
    <div class="client__info_block">
      <label for="tab-btn-3" class="client__info-text">Payment Details</label>
    </div>
    <div class="client__info_block">
      <label for="tab-btn-4" class="client__info-text">My Bookings</label>
    </div>
    <div class="client__info_block">
      <label for="tab-btn-5" class="client__info-text">My documents</label>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-1" value="" checked>
  <div class="client__block" id="content-1">
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Name</p>
      <p class="client__block-text">Igor Vensko</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Email address</p>
      <p class="client__block-text">igor@vensko.net</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Phone number</p>
      <p class="client__block-text">+01 123 456 789</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Date of birth</p>
      <p class="client__block-text">Enter your date of birth</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Nationality</p>
      <p class="client__block-text">Polska</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Gender</p>
      <p class="client__block-text">I'm a man</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Address</p>
      <p class="client__block-text">Poland, Bialsytok</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-2" value="">
  <div class="client__block" id="content-2">
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Currency</p>
      <p class="client__block-text">PLN Polish Zlotyo</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Language</p>
      <p class="client__block-text client_icon-usa">American English</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-3" value="">
  <div class="client__block" id="content-3">
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Payment cards</p>
      <p class="client__block-text">Pay with new card</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit">Add card</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-4" value="">
  <div class="client__block" id="content-4">
    <div class="client__blocks-pic">
      <div class="client__block_pic">
        <img src="img/Winter park.jpg" alt="Winter park" class="slider__bar-image">
        <div class="client__block-signature">
          <p class="client__signature-text">Winter Park Ski Holiday</p>
          <a href="#" class="client__signature-link">Downoload pdf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="client__block_pic">
        <img src="img/Machu Picchu.jpg" alt="Winter park" class="slider__bar-image">
        <div class="client__block-signature">
          <p class="client__signature-text">Winter Park Ski Holiday</p>
          <a href="#" class="client__signature-link">Downoload pdf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="client__block_pic">
        <img src="img/Hivar.jpg" alt="Winter park" class="slider__bar-image">
        <div class="client__block-signature">
          <p class="client__signature-text">Winter Park Ski Holiday</p>
          <a href="#" class="client__signature-link">Downoload pdf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="client__block_pic">
        <img src="img/Wadi Musa.jpg" alt="Winter park" class="slider__bar-image">
        <div class="client__block-signature">
          <p class="client__signature-text">Winter Park Ski Holiday</p>
          <a href="#" class="client__signature-link">Downoload pdf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-5" value="">
  <div class="client__block" id="content-5">
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">ID scan.pdf</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit client__block-remove">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div class="client__block-info">
      <p class="client__block-intro">Trip plan.doc</p>
      <a href="#" class="client__block-edit client__block-remove">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div class="client__block-link">
      <a href="#" class="client__link">Upload documents</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.